# How can I bind JSON data to check box in JQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

I have a `@Html.CheckBox`which I load dynamically initially. I need to check/uncheck the check boxes with the values which I get through JSON data.

This is my html-

```
<td>
    @{
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Brands = ViewBag.GetBrands;
        foreach (var item in Brands)
        {                                                                   
            @Html.CheckBox(item.Text, false, new { item.Value })                                                                                                         <label>@item.Text</label><br />
        }
    }
</td>
```

This is what I tried in JQuery-

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.Configuration.OfficeBrands.count; i++) {
    $('#' + data.Configuration.OfficeBrands[i]).attr('checked', true);
}
```

`data.Configuration.OfficeBrands` has something like:

```
{
    { ID: 1, Text: Text1 },
    { ID: 2, Text: Text2 },
    //...
}
```

On load, I uncheck all the check boxes and I want to Check with the values in 
`data.Configuration.OfficeBrands`

Comment: Is the `ID` in the `OfficeBrands` array the `value` used in the checkbox?

Comment: yes `ID` is the `item.Value` in check box

Comment: try Configuration.OfficeBrands[i].ID in loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the `ID` value returned in your `OfficeBrands` array is the value of the checkbox, try this:

```
$.each(data.Configuration.OfficeBrands, function(i, brand) {
    $(':checkbox[Value="' + brand.ID + '"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

You may need to make the `:checkbox` selector more specific, depending on how many checkboxed are on your page.

Comment: I want to pass both `ID` and `Name` from `@Html.CheckBox`, thats why I couldn't be more specefic on `checkbox` name.

Comment: What did you mean by `brand` here- `ID` or `Name`?

Comment: @Sandy I forgot the `.ID` on `brand`. Try that.